# First Empty Row in Excel Spreadsheet using Javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, api, async-await, office-js

I was writing some code for automatically generating report and appending it into a Excel Web Spreadsheet. The program runs periodically, each run generates a set of data and inserts it into the first empty row in a specific spreadsheet file.

when writing code for inserting the row, I found that there is no API for searching where the first empty row is. Therefore I need to use the read API to search the row number for inserting new data.

The read API looks like this:

[image]

Since the spreadsheet is stored online, for performance issue, readCells is limited to return at most 30 rows of data each time.

Can I write a function to search the position of the first empty row in column A? Please note that the spreadsheet is for automatic reports, so the number of rows could be very large, and I want to generate the report quickly enough

Comment: What kind of spreadsheet are you working with? Google Sheets? Web Excel? Zoho Sheet?

Comment: Web Excel. You can assume that previous data were always written contiguously starting from row 1.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment you've said that we can assume that previously, data were always written contiguously starting from row 1. That being the case, you're looking for the handy [`getUsedRange` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheet?view=excel-js-preview#getusedrange-valuesonly-), probably with a `true` argument:

```
const range = worksheet.getUsedRange(true);
```

From the documentation:

> The used range is the smallest range that encompasses any cells that have a value or formatting assigned to them. If the entire worksheet is blank, this function will return the top left cell (i.e. it will not throw an error).
>
> Parameters
>
> - `valuesOnly` `boolean`
>
>   Optional. If true, considers only cells with values as used cells (ignoring formatting).

You'd get the used range, and then query the range to find out where it ends. The first blank row is the next row after the end of the range.

Comment: if i was not using Web Excel or Google Sheets and need to concretely use readCells method is there any leads?

Comment: @IsmailHossain - If you can **only** use `readCells`, you need to say that clearly in your question; not doing so makes the question **very** incomplete. You also need to say what inputs it supports, what it returns, etc. But if you're using Web Excel, you shouldn't be limited to just that one function.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I start from somewhere and get the next 30, and then check if any of the results is null. If not, I call the same function with another start that is 30 +previous start else I return start + index of null

```
 async function readCell(column, start) {
   const results = await readCells(`${column}${start}:${column}${start + 30}`);

   const foundIndex = results.find(element => element === null);

   if (foundIndex === -1) {
     return await readCell(column, start + 30);
   } else {
     return foundIndex + start;
   }
 }
```